# 503 Backend fetch failed and "VSM: Could not get hold of varnishd, is it running?" but it is active

Tags: nginx, drupal, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am having an issue with Varnish installed with Drupal on Nginx

nginx.conf:

```
user               daemon daemon;

worker_processes  auto;
error_log         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";
pid               "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/nginx.pid";

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format    main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status  $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log    "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log";

    client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path      "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         off;
    #gzip               off;
    #gzip_http_version  1.0;
    #gzip_comp_level    2;
    #gzip_proxied       any;
    #gzip_types         text/plain text/css text/js text/xml text/javascript application/javascript application/json application/xml application/xml+rss image/svg+xml;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    client_max_body_size 80M;
    server_tokens off;

    include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/*.conf";

    # HTTP Server
    server {
        # Port to listen on, can also be set in IP:PORT format
        listen  8080;

        include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";

    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;   
    }

    location /status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    }

    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ { 
    expires 7d;
    }

  }
}
```

drupal-https-server-block:

```
server {
  # Port to listen on, can also be set in IP:PORT format
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  root /opt/bitnami/drupal;
  # Catch-all server block See: 
  # https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names
  server_name _; 
  ssl_certificate bitnami/certs/server.crt; 
  ssl_certificate_key bitnami/certs/server.key; 
  location / {  
        # Set recommended by Nginx version
        proxy_http_version 1.1; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
      }

  location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off;
  }
  location = /robots.txt { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off;
  }
  location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ { return 403;
  }
  # Block access to scripts in site files directory
  location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ { deny all;
  }
  # Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
  location ~* ^/.well-known/ { allow all;
  }
  location @rewrite { rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
  }
  # Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
  location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ { deny all; return 404;
  }
  # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
  location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { try_files $uri @rewrite;
  }
  # Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come with a 
  # language prefix.
  location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
  }
  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ { 
  try_files $uri @rewrite; 
  expires max; 
  log_not_found off;
  }
  location ~ \.php$|^/update.php { 
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
  fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock; 
  fastcgi_index index.php; 
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename; 
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(|/.*)$; 
  include fastcgi_params;
  }
  include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";
}
```

drupal-server-block:

```
 server {
    # Port to listen on, can also be set in IP:PORT format
    listen 8080 http2 default_server; 
    root /opt/bitnami/drupal;
    # Catch-all server block See: 
    # https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names
    server_name _; 
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location /static/fonts  { add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;  alias /opt/bitnami/drupal/libraries/bootstrap/fonts/;
    }
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ { return 403;
    }
    # Block access to scripts in site files directory
    location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ { deny all;
    }
    # Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
    location ~* ^/.well-known/ { allow all;
    }
    location / { 

    if ($request_filename ~* ^.?/([^/]?)$) { 
    set $filename $1;
    }

    if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
           add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location @rewrite { rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }
    # Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ { deny all; return 404;
    }
    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }
    # Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come with a 
    # language prefix.
    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { try_files $uri 
      /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ { try_files $uri @rewrite; 
      expires max; log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$|^/update.php { 
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
    fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock; 
    fastcgi_index index.php; 
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename; 
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(|/.*)$; 
    include fastcgi_params;
    }        
    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";
  }
```

/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/6.1/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret$
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/varnishreload
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/default/varnish:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m"
```

default.vcl:

```
# This is the VCL configuration Varnish will automatically append to your VCL
# file during compilation/loading. See the vcl(7) man page for details on syntax
# and semantics.
# New users is recommended to use the example.vcl file as a starting point.
# 

vcl 4.1;

 sub vcl_recv {
   #if (req.http.host) {
    #set req.http.host = req.http.host.lower();
     #}
     if (req.method == "PRI") {
         /* This will never happen in properly formed traffic (see: RFC7540) */
         return (synth(405));
     }
     if (!req.http.host &&
       req.esi_level == 0 &&
       req.proto ~ "^(?i)HTTP/2") {
         /* In HTTP/1.1, Host is required. */
         return (synth(400));
     }
     if (req.method != "GET" &&
       req.method != "HEAD" &&
       req.method != "PUT" &&
       req.method != "POST" &&
       req.method != "TRACE" &&
       req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
       req.method != "DELETE" &&
       req.method != "PATCH") {
         /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
         return (pipe);
     }
 
     if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
         return (pass);
     }
     if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
         /* Not cacheable by default */
         return (pass);
     }
     return (hash);
 }

 sub vcl_pipe {
    # By default Connection: close is set on all piped requests, to stop
     # connection reuse from sending future requests directly to the
     # (potentially) wrong backend. If you do want this to happen, you can undo
     # it here.
     # unset bereq.http.connection;
     return (pipe);
 }
 
 sub vcl_pass {
     return (fetch);
 }
 
  sub vcl_hash {
      hash_data(req.url);
      if (req.http.host) {
          hash_data(req.http.host);
      } else {
          hash_data(server.ip);
      }
      return (lookup);
  }
# 
  sub vcl_purge {
      return (synth(200, "Purged"));
  }
# 
  sub vcl_hit {
      return (deliver);
  }
# 
  sub vcl_miss {
      return (fetch);
  }
# 
  sub vcl_deliver {
      return (deliver);
  if (obj.hits > 0) { set resp.http.Cache-Tags = "HIT";
  }
  else { set resp.http.Cache-Tags = "MISS";
  }
  }
# 
# /* * We can come here "invisibly" with the following errors: 500 & 503 */
  sub vcl_synth {
      set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
      set resp.http.Retry-After = "5";
      set resp.body = {"<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>"} + resp.status + " " + resp.reason + {"</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Error "} + resp.status + " " + resp.reason + {"</h1>
      <p>"} + resp.reason + {"</p>
      <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
      <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
      <hr>
      <p>Varnish cache server</p>
    </body>
  </html>
  "};
      return (deliver);
  }
# 
# #######################################################################
# # Backend Fetch
# 
  sub vcl_backend_fetch {
      if (bereq.method == "GET") {
          unset bereq.body;
      }
      return (fetch);
  }
# 
  sub vcl_backend_response {
      if (bereq.uncacheable) {
          return (deliver);
      } else if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
        beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "(?i)no-store" ||
        (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
          beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "(?i:no-cache|no-store|private)") ||
        beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
          #Mark as "Hit-For-Miss" for the next 2 minutes
          set beresp.ttl = 120s;
          set beresp.uncacheable = true;
      }
      return (deliver);
  }
# 
  sub vcl_backend_error {
      set beresp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
      set beresp.http.Retry-After = "5";
      set beresp.body = {"<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>"} + beresp.status + " " + beresp.reason + {"</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Error "} + beresp.status + " " + beresp.reason + {"</h1>
      <p>"} + beresp.reason + {"</p>
      <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
      <p>XID: "} + bereq.xid + {"</p>
      <hr>
      <p>Varnish cache server</p>
    </body>
  </html>
  "};
      return (deliver);
  }
# 
# #######################################################################
# # Housekeeping
  
  sub vcl_init {
      return (ok);
  }

  sub vcl_fini {
      return (ok);
  }

backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.connect_timeout = 600s;
.first_byte_timeout = 600s;

.probe = {
.timeout = 600s;
.interval = 10s;
.window = 5;
.threshold = 2;
.request = "GET HTTP/2"
"Host: https://www.example.com/index.html"
"Connection: close";
}
}
```

sudo systemctl status varnish:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-11-02 19:09:12 UTC; 1h 20min ago     
Docs: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/6.1/           
man:varnishd 
Main PID: 24668 (varnishd)    
Tasks: 217 (limit: 557)   
Memory: 12.1M   
CGroup: /system.slice/varnish.service           ├─24668 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m           └─24680 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m

Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: Warnings:
Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: VCL compiled.
Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: Debug: Version: varnish-6.0.8 revision 97e54ada6ac578af332e52b44d2038bb4fa4cd4a
Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: Debug: Platform: Linux,4.19.0-18-cloud-amd64,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-sdefault,-hcritbit
Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: Version: varnish-6.0.8 revision 97e54ada6ac578af332e52b44d2038bb4fa4cd4a
Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: Platform: Linux,4.19.0-18-cloud-amd64,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-sdefault,-hcritbit
Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: Debug: Child (24680) Started
Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: Child (24680) Started
Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: Info: Child (24680) said Child starts
Nov 02 19:09:12 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx varnishd[24668]: Child (24680) said Child starts
```

sudo netstat -tlnp:

```
LISTEN  24668/varnishd      tcp 0   0 0.0.0.0:80    0.0.0.0:*       
LISTEN  13255/nginx: master tcp 0   00.0.0.0:8080   0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  1352/sshd           tcp 0   00.0.0.0:22     0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  24668/varnishd      tcp 0   0127.0.0.1:353210.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  13255/nginx: master tcp 0   00.0.0.0:443    0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  537/trace-agent     tcp 0   0127.0.0.1:8126 0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  536/agent           tcp 0   0127.0.0.1:5000 0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  536/agent           tcp 0   0127.0.0.1:5001 0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  13201/mysqld        tcp 0   0127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  589/redis-server 12 tcp 0   0127.0.0.1:6379 0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  853/process-agent   tcp6 0  0127.0.0.1:6062 0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  24668/varnishd      tcp6 0  0:::80          :::*
LISTEN  1352/sshd           tcp6 0  0:::22          :::*
LISTEN  589/redis-server 12 tcp6 0  0::1:6379       :::*
```

sudo apt-get install libwww-perl && GET -Used http://localhost:80/index.html:

```
503 Backend fetch failed
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 21:37:42 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
Age: 0
Retry-After: 5
Server: Varnish
Content-Length: 310
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 21:37:42 GMT
Client-Peer: 127.0.0.1:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Title: 503 Backend fetch failed
X-Varnish: 32773
```

Answer (score 1):

Please run `varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health` to monitor your backend health and to figure out what status could the health probe is getting.

Based on that you'll find out why Varnish is returning a `503 Backend fetch failed` error.

It's very likely that it's because of the HTTP/2 request in your probe. If I remember correctly, Varnish does not support HTTP/2 at the backend side, only at the client side.

Comment: a slew of 0 Backend_health - default Still sick 4 --- X-R- 0 2 5 0.000198 0.000000 "" and similar. I tried a bit to play with the probe values, to deactivate it completely (it doesn't even give me any more error signals but nothing, dead), I tried a bit to play with the values of nginx (for example by deactivating gzip) but nothing, the 503 remains. I'm afraid the road will be long or I'll never find out where the mistake lies.

Comment: @DantinoEsposito Try removing `http2 ` from your Nginx vhost configuration. As mentioned: Varnish doesn't support HTTP/2 backend connections.

Comment: a glimmer of hope arose when I removed http2 since at least from that moment an answer was provided, not pleasant ie HTTP / 1.1 400 Bad Request but there is. Unfortunately I still can't see X-Varnish. With sudo cat error.log from nginx it gives me 130 client sent invalid request while reading client request line, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET HTTP / 1.1" while access.log gives me "GET HTTP /1.1 "400 150" - "" - "" - ". I didn't even remember how many changes to the nginx.conf file and to that of the related block port 443 anymore, but X-Varnish is just a hope.

Comment: @DantinoEsposito Just for clarity, can you please update the config in your question with the config you currently have after the modifications? My initial hunch is to remove the `.request` property in the VCL backend probe and replace it with a `.url` property that points to `/`. Maybe that will take care of the `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` issues in the VSL output.